# How can I display the image from firebase without repetition

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-storage, angularfire2

**I already fetch the image from firebase storage. But it's repeating the image in the loop.**

**Typescript**

```
profileUrl: Observable<string | null>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.speakerService.getSpeakers().subscribe(speakers => {
      this.speakers = speakers;
      for(let i = 0; i < speakers.length; i++) {
        const ref = this.storage.ref(this.speakers[i].profilePath);
        this.profileUrl = ref.getDownloadURL();
        console.log(this.profileUrl);
      }          
    });
  }
```

**HTML**

```
  <div *ngFor="let speaker of speakers; let i = index;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:3rem">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <img [src]="profileUrl | async"  alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-50 mb-3">
        <h3>{{speaker.firstName}} {{speaker.lastName}} </h3>
        <h5 class="text-muted">{{speaker.specialization}}</h5>
        <p class="text-justify">{{speaker.bio}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**If you have solution please show me your code.**

Comment: can you show your `speakerService.getSpeakers()` code?

Comment: getSpeakers() {
    this.speakersRef = this.db.list('speakers');
    this.speakers = this.speakersRef.snapshotChanges().map(changes => {
      return changes.map(c => ({ key: c.payload.key, ...c.payload.val() }));
    });
    return this.speakers;
  }

Comment: I'm using angularfire2 libraries

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
speakers: Observable<any[]>;

this.speakers = this.speakerService.getSpeakers().map(changes => {
    return changes.map(data => {
        const ref = this.storage.ref(data.profilePath);
        ref.getDownloadURL().subscribe(url=>{
            data.profileUrl = url;
        })
        return data;
    })
});
```

In html try

```
 <div *ngFor="let speaker of speakers | async; let i = index;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:3rem">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <img [src]="speaker.profileUrl"  alt="" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-50 mb-3">
        <h3>{{speaker.firstName}} {{speaker.lastName}} </h3>
        <h5 class="text-muted">{{speaker.specialization}}</h5>
        <p class="text-justify">{{speaker.bio}}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: make sure here `data.profileUrl = url;` url is string. i didn't tried this code myself

Comment: I don't understand your code. But it works. It show multiple url from firebase. My problem now is I can't access it in iterrate

Comment: i got this error "of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.".

Comment: <div *ngFor="let speaker of speakers | async | json; let i = index;" class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12" style="margin-bottom:3rem">

Comment: <img [src]="speaker.profilePath" alt="Profile Picture" class="img-fluid rounded-circle w-50 mb-3">

Comment: do you have multiple urls(images) inside a  single speaker?

Comment: you dont need the json pipe in the ngFor. it should be `*ngFor="let speaker of speakers | async; let i = index;"`

Comment: only one url image for single speaker

Comment: Ok so in my solution is it showing one per speaker or all per speaker?

Comment: When i use this <pre>{{speakers | async | json}}<pre>

Comment: It's working now I have one more question. Which is good save the path and get the downloadUrl for accessing. Or saving the downloadUrl for accessing. What I'm talking is path = "../image/test/img.jpg". And downloadUrl = gs://nbms-3a2c5.appspot.com/speakers/d7jB3a1YeibEhCE4eJeIv6YVhgr1/1521873349392_person1.jpg. Which one is safe?.

Comment: I am not cleat what you meant by safe. if you want to prevent your images who can see, you can write security rules. check this [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/)

Comment: i always write the urls (`https://..../.profile.jpg`) of relevant users to database same time its uploaded to storage. then i only need to access the RTDB to get the urls.

Comment: Thank you for the information. It really helps me a lot